# Code contracts usage patterns when dealing with Files

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I've just started using Code Contracts with .NET and I had a guard clause like this

```
if (!file.Exists(path)) throw FileNotFoundException();
```

and replaced it with

```
Contract.Requires(File.Exists(path));
```

I'm not sure this is correct, because the contract will be dealing with an I/O concern, but not sure if this is a problem or not.

Basically the question is: Is there any problem in using Contracts to ensure I/O concerns (or external/non-unit concerns)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether a file exists is normally a pre-condition, you'd use Contract.Requires().  Enabling contract verification is optional and not normally turned on in the Release build.  Which makes your test disappear.

Frankly, you shouldn't write code like this.  Any attempt to use the file will generate an exception, it will be more informative than your version.  It includes the name of the file that could not be found.  More to the point, File.Exists() is unreliable on a multi-tasking operating system.  The thread could be pre-empted right after the Exists() call and another thread in another process could delete the file.  And you'll have a heisenbug on your hands: you'll get a FileNotFound exception, even though you tested that it existed.

My call: just delete the statement.  It causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: +1 This is key; ensures and requires only make sense for things that can be proven to be true.  Since files are partially outside the program's control, there is no provability.

Answer (score 3):

- If you are unsure whether the file exists, don't use exceptions.
- If the file should exist, but may not in some exceptional case, use exceptions.
- If you are sure that it is a programming error that the file does not exist, use Contract.Ensures.

Comment: Given that this is an API, I can not assume that the file exists or not, that is the whole point of the question. So that removes the first two bullet points, the third one , I m assuming you are talking about building a path, in that case, I also want to know what is happening.  I m sorry but I cant find the point of your answer

Comment: I think the point is that "contracts" in programming are used like `assert`: they document assumptions made by your code and guard against **programmer error** (the code being **used** or **changed** in a way that breaks the assumptions). They are not subsititutes for exceptions, which indicate that something has gone wrong, and would have gone wrong even if the code were perfect, e.g. trying to open a file you don't have permissions for. Your comment indicates ("I can not assume...") that this situation falls into the latter category, so you should use an exception and not a contract.

Comment: To help decide when to use which, ask "Would it be acceptable if the compiler removed this check in a release build?" Contracts and other `assert`-like things are for *testing and documenting code*. Exceptions are there to handle *unusual circumstances* at runtime.